# Simple menu with array homework problem wont execute

Tags: perl

My final lab for my programming and logic intro course will not execute, it has a quick CMD flash on the screen then nothing happens. I'm not sure if it is a syntax error or what. Thank you very much for any help.

```
#Part 2 Insert 1.0
@username=(“first”,“last”);
print "Please enter your first name: ";
$username[0] = <STDIN>;
chomp $username[0];

print "Please enter your last name: ";
$username[1] = <STDIN>;
chomp $username[1];

print "Your name is:\n";
print "$username[0]\n$username[1]\n";

print "Please enter a number\n";
$number1 = <STDIN>;
chomp $number1;
#Part 2 Insert 1.0 - END


print "Please enter a second number\n";
$number2 = <STDIN>;
chomp $number2;

while ( $number2 == 0 )
{
  print "You entered $number2\nPlease enter a non-zero number\n";
  $number2 = <STDIN>;
  chomp $number2;
}

print "Please enter your first name\n";
$name=<STDIN>;
chomp $name;

print "$name, how many times do you want to run your program?\n";
$total_loops=<STDIN>;
chomp $total_loops;

print "\n$name, you entered $number1 and $number2\n";

for($ctr=1; $ctr <= $total_loops; $ctr++)
{
  print("\nDisplaying $ctr of $total_loops loops \n\n");
  print("Please make a selection using the menu below\n");
  print "1 - Subtract \n";
  print "2 - Divide\n";
  print "3 - Modulus\n";
  print "4 - Exit\n";
  $answer = <STDIN>;
  chomp $answer;

#next line edited to use lab4 part 2 array
  print "$username[0] $username[1] You selected $answer as your menu choice\n\n";

if($answer == 1)
{
  $sub = $number1 - $number2;
  print("$number1 - $number2 is $sub");
 }
elsif($answer == 2)
{
  $quot = $number1/$number2;
  print "$number1 / $number2 is $quot";
}
elsif($answer == 3)
{
   $mod=$number1 % $number2;
   print "$number1 % $number2 is $mod";
 }
elsif($answer == 4)
{
    print "Exiting program";
    exit 0;
 }
else
 {
    print "$answer is not a valid menu choice! Please retry.";
  }
  print ("\n"); #blank line
}
```

Expected - 
prompt for name and assign to array
prompt for numbers
menu for operation selection 
print results with assigned name from array

Actual- Quick CMD window flash then nothing

Comment: This code works for me in a Linux terminal, as it stands.  And it works as intended :).  I have no clue why it doesn't run for you.  Where do you run it? Can you run any (_simplest_) program the way you are trying to run this?

Comment: No, for some reason, I can not get anything to run on my pc, no clue why. I had this issue last lab as well, it ran on school PC's but not mine, I'm glad I can submit it at least, thank you for that.

Comment: The quotation marks on the second line (`@username = (…)`) look like “smart quotes” (`“”`, not `""`). Disable this option in your text editor and retype those characters.

Comment: @duskwuff Right, I forgot to mention that I had to fix that.  But, it throws an error and prints it loud and clear?

Comment: "_I'm glad I can submit it at least, thank you for that._"  -- um, please don't just take my word for it :).  Yes, it runs, and I checked your menu as well, but I didn't test properly (and we aren't even talking about the program design).  Plus, you absolutely do want to fix that.  I don't use Windows regularly and I don't know what to suggest :(

Comment: I've removed the "padre" tag. The editor that you're using here is a complete red herring. (Also, Padre has been abandoned - I don't recommend using it.)

Comment: You are making things much harder for yourself by not including `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your program. You should also add `use diagnostics;` for more verbose error messages.

Comment: *it ran on school PC's but not mine* Just a quick, random, thought. Do you have Perl installed on your PC?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're double-clicking the program in some kind of directory list which starts the program in a command window and then immediately closes - not giving you time to see what message it displays. The solution is, surely, to open your own command window and then type `perl your_program_name.pl` at the prompt. An already-open command window will not close when the program exits and you will be able to see the error.

(But if I had to guess, I'd suggest that the problem was the "smart quotes" in the line where you define `@username`.)